# UserNamePasswordValidator with basicHttpbinding and ssl

Tags: wcf

is it possible to have BasicHttpBinding with an Custom UserNamePasswordValidator and have transport security?

- I have tried with wsHttpBinding but when I cant make an php soap client explained in this link.
  [Using SOAP wsHttpBinding from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642874/using-soap-wshttpbinding-from-php)
- and in this guide they talk as if custom UserNamePasswordValidator wont get called in basicHttpBinding.
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind

I just get InvalidSecurity from php soap and if I trace the error `Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.`

currently im using basicHttpBinding with `TransportWithMessageCredential` with `clientCredentialType="UserName" />`

i'll include the config if its necessary but I just need to know if it can be done or else I guess I have to call the validate method inside every `[OperationContract]`? havent tested this yet but seen others talk about it.

Comment: I believe <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">                   <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/></security> would work with Custom user name password validator for basicHttpBinding.

Comment: hmm cant seem to get it to work with php soap, maybe I can try to make an wcf client and try to make Custom user name password validator to execute. dont know what else to try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I dont know how it works but apperently I did right all along. what made it to work was that in my php code when i specify username and password that the parameters was named.

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://wsdl"), array('login' => "user123", 
                                                    'password' => "pass123"));
```

and the same in my custom username password validator. i had `userName` and `Password` before on both places and that didnt work. So i dont know the difference but it works now... maybe someone else can answer why it works this way.